# Preferable way to manage data, classes or arrays?

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns

I'm making a turn based RPG in Flash, with AS 3 as the language, though I'm pretty sure you could help me regardless of the language you are using.

Basically, my idea was to put all of my weapon data on a single multi-dimensional array. Now if I want to add a weapon into my inventory, easy, i just use `inventoryArray.push(weaponArray[1])` Easy, I just added the weapon into my inventory.

I've been looking into Design patterns, and it seems that most OOP designs are using classes and inheriting from a superclass. `Component-->Weapon-->Sword-->LongSword.`

What should I go with, putting all data in one array or using the inherit style, with one class containing a single weapon?

Any Ideas are welcome! I basically know how to make the game in itself, its just that I don't know some patterns I should go with.

Comment: Is this a side project for you? If it is I would turn it into a learning session. Take a day or four and read up on design patterns find the ones that work best with AS3 and then single out the ones that will work with your game. You will find you will need atleast some bit of inheritance like Laurent stated.

Comment: Yes it is a learning session. I am able to create games no problem, but I have just decided to throw myself into the dark abyss of OOP.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the objects in your game are going to have some properties in common - for example, maybe they will all have an ID, a name and a description.

If you don't use inheritance, you will have all your classes having this duplicate information in them, which will make your game hard to maintain.

If you do use inheritance, you can have all these common properties in a base (probably abstract) class and have all the other classes inherit from it. So yes, the design pattern you looked at is the way to go.

Also, rather than do `inventoryArray.push(weaponArray[1])`, you should also create an `Inventory` class with an `add()` method. That will allow you to dispatch events when an object is added to the inventory. The front end can then listen to this event and, for example, update the inventory graphics. In general, you should never use generic Flash objects (Array, Object, etc.) for potentially complex objects like inventory, characters, etc. Using your own custom classes allows you to easily extend them as your game becomes more complex.

Comment: Is the deep hierarchy pattern the best way for this sort of stuff? What about composites?

Comment: These two patterns are not mutually exclusive. You'll most likely need a hierarchy of classes, and you might also want to use the composite pattern (personally, I'd avoid, in order to keep things simple).

Comment: Okay thanks. Just another quick question, but all things under my sword class simply change data (e.g. changes weight and damage to another value). Will making a class for every "sword" weapon changing only in data preferable? I was hoping for something such as a list of all "sword" weapons, but I guess adding a new weapon will be easier, since I just need to add another class instead of changing my list. Sorry if my question is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say composition over inheritance is the way to go.

There is a basic gameobject class that could be extended to weapons,rings,helms,shields, potions etc. These all have a set of restrictions that can be managed through inheritance (like the fact that you can place a weapon in hands and inventory only). But abilities of all of these (how they affect the character) should be done through compositions. Every time you add an object to the sash, hand, head etc. they affect the character through composition. So when you're dealing with the character's action, you don't loop through every object, you just use the composite function like attack, which has all the functions of the inventory that apply part of the character action.

---

The other design pattern you can look into is the decorator pattern. I find that the outcome is pretty similar to composition. *"While the decorator pattern lets us add responsibilities to objects without subclassing, the composite pattern has a different goal: structuring classes in order to handle related objects in the same way, and multiple objects can be treated as one."* [source](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~ayala/SENG/seng609-04/Assignments/decoratorNcomposite.htm)

example of decorator pattern: 
http://www.as3dp.com/2011/06/well-armored-warrior-decorator-for-beginners/